# How to delay for ajax requests with onkeyup and start count delay again when onkeyup?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How to delay for ajax requests with onkeyup and start count delay again when onkeyup ?

for example code, When user fill data into `id="fname"` (`onkeyup`)

span `id="loading"` will show

and then 2 sec, data will post to `test.php`

This code work good.

But i want to apply like this

When user fill data into `id="fname"` (`onkeyup`)

span `id="loading"` will show

within 2 sec user fill data into `id="fname"` (`onkeyup`) again , clear delay time and start count delay again,

and then 2 sec, data will post to `test.php`

How can i do that ?

```
<form id="fid">
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<span id="loading" style="display: none;">LOADING</span>
<span id="myplace"></span>
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    $('#myplace').hide();
    $("#loading").show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'test.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#fid').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#loading").hide();
                    $('#myplace').show();
                    $('#myplace').html(data);
                }
            }
        )
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout will give you back a unique id. Now if the user types within the "timeout time", you can use this id to cancel the previous timeout funciton.

```
var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){},2000);
clearTimeout(timeoutId)
```

EDIT:

With your code, it should look something like this:

```
<form id="fid">
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<span id="loading" style="display: none;">LOADING</span>
<span id="myplace"></span>
</form>

<script>
(function(){
var currentTimeoutId;
function myFunction() {
    $('#myplace').hide();
    $("#loading").show();

    if(currentTimeoutId){
       clearTimeout(currentTimeoutId);
    }

    currentTimeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        currentTimeoutId = null;
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'test.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#fid').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#loading").hide();
                    $('#myplace').show();
                    $('#myplace').html(data);
                }
            }
        )
    }, 2000);
}
}());
</script>
```

Comment: if this one fits your need, please flag it as the solution to close this question

Comment: What's happend in slow connection case and 2 ajax requests at same time??? 2sec is too much to wait until send request..

Comment: And about global scope in your case. If you write var currentTimeoutId; in global scope = use global scope and have access by window object too.  var currentTimeoutId same as window.currentTimeoutId here.

Comment: correct. I've just changed the code that has been provided. I would never do it like he did, but it does the job. See my edits

Comment: Just in this case. Same for me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a little different algorithm:

abort ajax request each time user change value of INPUT, and send new one on stop typing:

define pointer for timeout and ajax

```
window.tPointer = null;
window.ajaxPointer = null;
```

then define event handler function

```
$("#fname").on("keyup" function(e){
```

stop bubbling event

```
    e.stopPropagation();
```

clear timeout if it's exists

```
    if(window.ajaxPointer != null) {
```

define timeout for .2 sec for example

```
    clearTimeout(window.tPointer);
        window.ajaxPointer = null
    }
```

check is ajax not aborted?

```
    if(window.ajaxPointer != null) {
```

abort ajax, try{}catch{} construction for ignore exception in case

```
        try{window.ajaxPointer.abort();}cachet(e){}
    }
```

define timeout for .2 sec for example

```
    window.tPointer = setTimeout(myFunction, 200);
}
```

modify functon for a little bit

```
function myFunction() {
```

set timeout pointer to null

```
    window.tPointer = null;        
    $('#myplace').hide();
    $("#loading").show();
```

set ajax pointer to ajax request object

```
    window.ajaxPointer = $.ajax ({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#fid').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#myplace').html(data);
        },
        complete: function(){
```

remove hiding of loading in comlete

```
            $("#loading").hide();
            $('#myplace').show();
```

set ajax pointer to null

```
            window.ajaxPointer = null;
        }
    })
}
```

Complete code

```
window.tPointer = null;
window.ajaxPointer = null;

$("#fname").on("keyup" function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    if(window.ajaxPointer != null) {
        clearTimeout(window.tPointer);
        window.ajaxPointer = null
    }

    if(window.ajaxPointer != null) {
        try{window.ajaxPointer.abort();}cachet(e){}
    }

    window.tPointer = setTimeout(myFunction, 200);
}

function myFunction() {
    window.tPointer = null;        
    $('#myplace').hide();
    $("#loading").show();
    window.ajaxPointer = $.ajax ({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#fid').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#myplace').html(data);
        },
        complete: function(){
            $("#loading").hide();
            $('#myplace').show();
            window.ajaxPointer = null;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: don't be evil! Don't polute the global scope

Comment: @christian sometimes using global scope is more fast, easy and clear way =) and could not be evil as here. Not all of tasks require to use OOP =) and not all of cases forbid to use global scope.

Comment: I absolutly disagree. It's always a bad idea to use the global scope. Either because of security reasons or because of compatibility to other libs..